# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'locals'

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pygame

I am trying to go through the book "Making Games with Python & Pygame" and I got this error message while I tried the first blankgame.py example. When I used

> from pygame.locals import *

I got NO error with

> if event.type == QUIT:

However. if I tried

> if event.type == pygame.locals.QUIT

without importing at the beginning and excuted, the error occured. Could anybody help me with this and tell me the difference between importing before hand and using the full constant path reference of QUIT.

Thank you.

Comment: Everything in `pygame.locals` is now local, so you don't need the prefix to reference them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

That will import everything from 'pygame.locals' into your local namespace. So you would access the members of that module as if they are in your own current namespace. Hence you should not prefix calls with pygame.locals. If you call with a prefix like pygame.locals.QUIT it will be an error.

```
import pygame.locals
```

This will load everything from 'pygame.locals' but not into your namespace. You still have to prefix calls with 'pygame.locals' like pygame.locals.QUIT.

Using pygame.locals.QUIT without using the above import will cause you an error since it never loaded the module pygame.locals

Comment: Hi @user3885927! Thank you very much for your help, and it indeed solved my problem. By the way, may I ask you that even if I wrote `import pygame` at the beginning, should I also put `import pygame.locals` then?

Comment: Jiaweik, that depends on how pygame.__init__ is implemented. For example you can `import os` and then use `os.path.exists`, because os makes os.path available. Rule of thumb is: follow the examples from documentation, or just try it and see if it works, or look at __init__.py file.